# Linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, gcc, kubuntu

I run into problem compiling a kernel scheduler for testing

the compiling error

```
 linux-2.6.32-rc3/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:86:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory
```

Do I get this error because the kernel is too old?

kernel

```
uname -r

4.1.0-3-generic
```

gcc

```
gcc --version

gcc-5.real (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
```

So if this is the reason for the compilation error - what solutions are available? Should I for instance update the kernel - how do I do that? Or regress to an earlier version of gcc? Other sugestions?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're building version 2.6.32-rc3 of the kernel?

Comment: @StephenKitt - its just for testing and this was the tarball the institution gave me (linsched-2.6.32-rc3.tar.gz). At the moment I dont know the alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

Any kernel older than 3.18 will not compile using gcc 5. Use an older compiler.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to install gcc-4.9 to be able to compile 3.xx kernels.

but then, next question would be: "**how to switch for gcc-4.9 for kernel compilation?**"

instead, [the simpler answer would be here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802473/compile-an-old-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/37802981#37802981) - just download missing file into `include/linux` folder

unfortunately gcc5 dislike "**extern inline**" construction at all, so you'll have to proceed with `grep -sRl "extern inline" .|xargs sed -i -e "s/extern inline/inline/g"` for all your kernel source code before moving forward with any compilation

Comment: Instead of replacing `extern inline` just add `-std=c90` or `gnu90` to CFLAGS. The `extern inline` issue is a C standard problem

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the kernel sources. The compiler is looking for that header file.

This link will get you a version of the kernel source tree that should be mostly similar to what you are looking for.

https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/longterm/v2.6.32/linux-2.6.32.71.tar.xz

Answer (score 0):

Simply:
Get an older version of GCC and do `make CC=gcc-4.9` in your kernel directory to compile using the `4.9` gcc version.